# Tesserocr vs Pytesseract Speed comparison

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, tesseract, python-tesseract

From what I've been able to gather online, when trying to extract text from multiple images in python, using the `tesserocr` library should be faster than using `pytesseract` as it doesn't have to initiate the tesseract framework each time, it just makes the prediction. However, I implemented two functions as can be seen below:

```py
api = tesserocr.PyTessBaseAPI()

# tessserocr function
def tessserocr_extract(p):
    api.SetImageFile(p)
    text = api.GetUTF8Text()
    return text
```

```py
# pytesseract function
def pytesseract_extract(p):
    pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = path_to_tesseract

    img = Image.open(p)

    #Extract text from image
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
    return text
```

When I use both functions to extract text from 20 images, the `tesserocr` library is always slower the first time around. When I try to extract the text from the same set of images, the `tesserocr` library is faster though, maybe due to some image caching. I have also tried using `tessdata_fast` and observed the same result. I did also try using `api.SetImage(...)` after loading the image using `PIL`, and it was still slower.

The images are mostly screenshots of websites that vary in size.

Am I doing something incorrectly, or is `tesserocr` simply slower than `pytesseract` for extracting text from multiple images?

Answer (score 0):

In my own tests conducted on two different machines (12-core and 48-core servers), and using two different file sizes (2-page and 80+ page PDF files), lack of modeling pipeline memoization (which seems to be impossible in `pytesseract`) causes it to lag `tessserocr` by 50% for small files and by 150-200% for large files.

Answer (score -1):

Do not measure something you do not understand (... *maybe due to some image caching* ... suggests you do not really understand the code you posted above). Even if you get correct results (which you did not), you will not be able to interpret them.

If you were to analyse the differences between `pytesseract` and `tesserocr`, you would see that it is not possible for `pytesseract` to be faster than `tesserocr` (It has to perform several extra steps to reach the same state as `tesserocr`). In any case, on modern hardware the difference in speed is very small.

Comment: I am aware of how both of them work at a high level as I highlighted in the first paragraph of the post. I am asking precisely because I understand that the results shouldn't be possible. I have tried scraping text from the same images and on more than one run, the results were such that `pytesseract` offered equal or sometimes better performance than `tesserocr`. I have since tried out `pytessy` too and found that it provided the best results _(significantly so)_. Do you have any insight as to why this could be happening ?

Comment: I am not familiar with `pytessy` (thanks for hint), but it also wraps tesseract library as `tesserocr` instead of executable (`pytesseract`). 
`pytesseract` not only loose time with the initialization of OCR engine in each run but also it [stores input and reads output from disk](https://github.com/madmaze/pytesseract/blob/586809affde287be2a98a79c38cf5feb98c1bfd8/pytesseract/pytesseract.py#L267-L293). With wrapping library you can do this operation in memory. Anyway speed delay is not huge. Try to provided full code how do you do measuring, maybe problem is in your code...

Comment: pytessy does not seems to be actively maintained. I suggest to try [pyocr](https://gitlab.gnome.org/World/OpenPaperwork/pyocr), that do the tesseract wrapping similar way and is IMO more mature then pytessy